# function to find the cumulative sum of every 5 elements.in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

There can be some elements which might not be of int type, the function will need to gracefully handle the exceptions and pass to the next element. Function is supposed to return a list where every element is expected to be the cumulative sum of every 5 elements in input list.

```
sample_input = [50, 30, 20, 0, "catch_me", 0, "you_got_me", "did_you_really_catch", 40, 50, "20", 0, 0, 0, 10]
expected_output = [100, 190, 200]
```

I have tried so far below snip of code

```
a=[]
count=0
n=5
for i in sample_input:

    if isinstance(i,int):
        for j in range(len(sample_input)/5):
            count+=i
            a.append(count)
print (a)
```

can some one please suggest me to how to get expected output for this problem

Comment: expected result to be [100,190,200] , cumulative sum of every 5 element and discarding string type element in addition

Answer (score 1):

First filter the ints them sum it:

```py
filtered = [x for x in sample_input if isinstance(x, int)]

result = []
cumsum = 0
for i in range(0, len(filtered), 5):
    cumsum += sum(filtered[i:i + 5])
    result.append(cumsum)

print(result) # [100, 190, 200]
```

Comment: Your filtering won't respect the OP's request of count each grouped 5 items. It might work for the example provided, but won't work if for example you change ```30 to '30'``` in the first group

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_input = [50, 30, 20, 0, "catch_me", 0, "you_got_me", "did_you_really_catch", 40, 50, "20", 0, 0, 0, 10]
nbr_of_item_per_list = 5


def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

results = []
total = 0
for sample in chunks(sample_input, nbr_of_item_per_list):
    # get the sum of the yield 5 items and add it to the total
    total += sum(value for value in sample if isinstance(value, int))
    results.append(total)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[100, 190, 200]
```